# How can one enable double-tapping to zoom in Firefox?

Tags: 12.04, browser, firefox-extensions

I want to have a double-tap zoom functionality (like on Android or iOS devices) in my Firefox web browser using the left mouse button. Is it possible to change some browser settings in order to get it to work?

Comment: You say this applies to 12.04 too?

Comment: @mateo_salta I use firefox, and chrome in very rare cases

Comment: @Seth yes, I just upgraded to 12.04 and there is no such functionality in my browser

Comment: Can't seem to find any plugins meeting your needs. In the meantime, in firefox `Ctrl  Mouse_Scroll_Up/Down` will zoom

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried firefox extensions? This one, for example has shortcuts that late you zoom

[zoom-page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-page/?src=search)

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: it offers an alternative